# Vmware и Mac OS

Tags: mac, vmware, виртуализация

Доброго времени суток!Я решил начать учиться писать приложения под iOS. Хотелось бы пока не покупать компы от Apple. Так что желательно установить Mac OS на виртуалку.Не могли бы вы посоветовать нормальную версию для AMD Phenom ?Чтобы поддерживались требуемое ПО для разработки и проверки(виртуалка iOS).Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите на процессоре поддержку аппаратной виртуализации, это можно посмотреть у производителя (Intel VT-x or AMD-V), в качестве виртуалки все же рекомендую VirtualBox, Хакинтош встает нормально, как ставить есть на офф сайте хакинтоша, потребуется ISO образ мака.

Answer (score 0):

Для работы на виртуалке нужен довольно мощный компьютер. Если "позволяет религия" можно установить на PC образ Hacintosh, можно взять на любой процессор на http://rutracker.org/forum/index.php или http://www.tonymacx86.com/61-unibeast-install-os-x-mountain-lion-any-supported-intel-based-pc.html

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри [link text](http://staiki.net/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=16489)

Answer (score 0):

попробуй. http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3331891А ты не пробовал поставить MAC на физическую машину? Потом можно удалить за ненадобностью.Сама не работала в MAC и точно сказать не могу, но знаю таких товарищей, кто устанавливал на физ.машину,работал и потом сносил. На виртуалке частенько всё через одно место.